# Why do we have null array declaration in java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, declaration

```
int[] numbers;
```

I cannot use the numbers array after declaring like above without initializing.
Gone through all the steps of using it. Tried to assign values, used fill and tried length and came to conclusion that it's wrong way to declare an array, but I don't understand why Java has such syntax. It's confusing.

Comment: How many `numbers` should it have without *initialization*? What you have posted is a *declaration*. Java supports (but does not **require**) *initialization* and *declaration* at the same time, `int[] numbers = {1,2,3};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because sometimes you need to initialize the array based on conditional runtime information:

```
void syntheticExample(int[] these, int[] those, int[] theOthers) {
    int[] numbers;

    // ...some work...

    if (/*...some condition...*/) {
        numbers = these;
    } else {
        // ...more work, then:
        if (/*...some other condition...*/) {
            numbers = those;
        } else if (/*...some further condition...*/) {
            numbers = theOthers;
        } else {
            // We'll use our own numbers
            numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
        }
    }

    // ...use `numbers`...
}
```

It's the same as the reason we can declare any other kind of variable without initializing it. Declaration and initialization/assignment are *different things*, and sometimes they need to happen at different times.

---

And [Jean-Baptiste's distinction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829827/157247) is useful and important here: `numbers` in the above is a variable, which contains an object reference. What it *refers to* is an array (or nothing, if we assign `null` to it).

Answer (score 2):

You are just defining a reference to an array, but this reference doesn't refer anything until you state it. For it, you need to **construct** a array, and the only way for this is to use `new` and link this newly allocated object to the reference. It is very consistent in Java, since you understand what object are and how they are built.

```
int []ref_array;         // this is NOT an array, but a reference to an array, actually refers nothing
ref_array = new int[10]; // new construct a object that contains 10 ints and array refers to it.
ref_array[3];            // means get the object that ref_array refers, get the array inside and take the 4th value stored in it. A handy shortcut...
```

Comment: Yes, all java objects can be declared, it refers nothing. But pls explain me why such codings in practice. For example if i create

Comment: Yes, all java objects can be declared, it refers nothing.  For example if i create object obj[] ; then i have to put the reference of new object into it .. i cannot put string object without casting. But pls explain me why such codings in practice. Why are we allowed to declare objects without initizaliation. In case of primitive atleast default values are given. but with objects it points to nothing or the variable stores nothing.

Comment: No you don't declare object without initializing. You declare reference without initializing. There is no default value provided, even for primitive types! The Java compiler verify that you are not trying to read a variable that have not been initialized... Just try: `int i; System.out.println(i);`

Comment: Agreed what i meant is initizaliation of primitive. Thanks